# Samsung Galaxy S3 unable to power on after shutting off randomly

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.3-jelly-bean, power-on

I am a problem with my Samsung Galaxy S3. There will be a time when the phone will shut off, and I won't be able to turn it on whatever I do (e.g. Pressing the power, home, or volume buttons). However, I tried stuff and this came to be a temporary solution. I would remove the battery from the phone for a few seconds and put it back again. Then I would plug in the phone and it would work again.

Nonetheless, it is only a temporary solution and the phone may turn off again sometime.

Can someone identify the problem?

Comment: Clearly the actions of reseating the battery and juicing it up, indicate a hardware issue related to the battery connections. Have you cleaned the contacts? Do you treat the device in such a way that it flexes so battery contacts are lost?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your phone have hardware problem . It loose the contact of power supply internally. May be there was damage in power IC.

If your phone is in warranty period give it to Samsung care otherwise take a help of local phone repairing center for cheap solution.